# Bash Script to generate csv file from text

Tags: bash, shell, sh, export-to-csv

I have a text file with records:

```
  Data1

  Data2

  ...

  Data50
```

I have to create a .csv file from the above text file in the following format:

```
Type |  Count | Name

Def |    u1 |    Data1

Def |    u2  |     Data2

....  |  .....   |  ....

Def  |   u50   | Data50
```

i need a bash script to generate the .csv file from the text file. I am new to shell scripting! I have gone through basics of awk and sed as well. 
I have a vague idea like:

```
#!/bin/bash
type="Def"
x=1
count="u"
for F in ../test.txt
do
    {
       read \n
       echo "$type, $count$x, $..." >> ../test.csv
       x=x+1
    } < $F

done
```

I do understand that the field separator is '\n'. I am kind of lost after that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save this in a file, e.g. makecsv.rc:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Type,Count,Name
x=0
for f in `cat`
do
   x=`expr $x + 1`
   echo Def,u$x,$f
done
```

then run as:

```
cat  ../test.txt | ./makecsv.rc > ../test.csv
```

if needed, you do `chmod +x makecsv.rc`

The advantage is that the input/output file names are not `hardcoded`

Comment: Just use `"$1"` and `"$2"` if you don't want to hardcode file names.  The `cat` in backticks is rather horrible.

Comment: This was super helpful, as I would need to execute it at definite intervals with different files! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tripleee you are right. But in my timezone it is definitely time to go home. Please propose how to avoid the TWO `cat`s: in the script and on the command line.

Comment: Improvement eliminating one `cat`: in the script use: `for f in 'cat $1'` and on the command line use: `./makecsv.rc < ../test.txt > ../test.csv`   Please use back quotes around the cat in the script

Comment: I added a snippet to my own answer. Yours could be similarly refactored, but then it would be pretty much the same answer...

Comment: @jm666 Correct. My solution can be improved to replace `cat` with a line reading command. However, the original problem did not mention spaces. Also, a new solution will blow up if the input contains a comma, but this can also be fixed by adding quotes. But then you might need to double-quote quotes in the input. This kind of simple scripts can only solve simple problems. Otherwise you would better look for a proper CSV library.

Comment: @Roland my comment is for the **other** users, who could use the solution and they could have a space. Remember, the answers are for the future users too. I not want be an critic of your answer, but honestly i agree with @tripleee - the simple `cat` in backtick is really horrible and it is against any good bash practice. Also, in any modern shell the `$(command)` is more preferred as the backticks.

Comment: @jm666 thank you for pointing to the newer method for command substitution. I learned the backticks some 20 years ago, but am eager to learn new ways. I understand that `$(...)` is pretty much equivalent to backticks, and that most people prefer the newer method. But I don't agree with qualifications as `horror`, just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop will only loop a single time, it loops over the tokens you list and you only listed one (which looks like a file name, so I'm guessing you want to loop over lines in the file):

```
#!/bin/bash
type="Def"
x=1
count="u"
while read value; do
   echo "$type, $count$x, $value"
   let x++
done <../test.txt > ../test.csv
```

You could also use an external utility for the running numbers:

```
nl ../test.txt |
while read -r x value; do
    echo "$type,$count$x,$value"
done >../test.csv
```

Redirecting outside the loop is more efficient because the shell won't have to close and reopen the output file.

If you want to pass in a variable file name on the command line, just replace the hardcoded `../test.txt` with `"$1"`. You could similarly parametrize the output file name, but I would simply remove the output redirection, and leave it  to the caller to decide what to do with the script's output.

If you need to read multiple fields and split on comma, tweak your `IFS`.

```
nl -s , ../test.txt |
while IFS=, read -r i first second rest; do
    printf "%i,%s,u%i,%s\n" $i "$first" "$second" "$rest"
done
```

(`printf` is recommended over `echo`, especially if your output requirements are nontrivial. I fail to quote `$i` specifically to get rid of any leading whitespace added by `nl` before the line number.  Otherwise, you should generally always use double quotes around your variables unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value.)

Comment: don't forget the csv header line! which is still easy to add in your solutions

Comment: `x=((x+1))` did not work for me, too bad, I don't like `expr`

Comment: @Roland use `x=$((x+1))` or `let x++`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time. You got it correct, i want to read multiple lines in a file. Like I mentioned I am new to bash scripting. So I tried the first code you provided, its giving me syntax error at 'done'! Can you give me some detail about external utility thing.

Comment: The addition should work with: `x=$((x + 1))`  but @jm666 you were faster :-)  I also like your 2nd option.

Comment: @TamaghnaGuhaThakurta just try `nl ../test.txt` at the shell prompt, and try `man nl`

Comment: @jm666  as OP apparently is new to shell scripting, could you care about explaining the syntax of your 1st solution? I might also learn here ...

Comment: Thanks for comments; fixed.

Comment: There are excellent reasons to omit the header line.  As the OP's example didn't have one either, I didn't add one; and would recommend against it if there was a header line.

Answer (score 1):

If you have perl installed, the

```
perl -lnE 'say qq{Def,u$.,"$_"}' < inputfile
```

will do the job.

demo:

the `seq -f 'Some Data%g' 50` will generate lines like:

```
Some Data1
Some Data2
...
Some Data50
```

so the

```
seq -f 'Some Data%g' 50 | perl -lnE 'say qq{Def,u$.,"$_"}'
```

prints

```
Def,u1,"Some Data1"
Def,u2,"Some Data2"
...
Def,u49,"Some Data49"
Def,u50,"Some Data50"
```

I quoted the last field, because in the input you could get `,` or spaces.

based on @Roland comment, adding a header line:

```
cat data | (echo 'Type,Count,Name' ; perl -lnE 'say qq{Def,u$.,"$_"}')
```

or

```
perl -lnE 'BEGIN{say q{Type,Count,Name}}say qq{Def,u$.,"$_"}'
```

If you want `bash` solution, simply use:

```
cat -n filename | sed 's/ *\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/Def,u\1,"\2"/'
```

or save the

```
cat -n - | sed 's/ *\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/Def,u\1,"\2"/'
```

into some file, like "makecsv" and use it as

```
./makecsv < data
```

*Ps: hmm.. the @tripleee's `nl` is shorter as `cat -n` ;)*

Comment: it is easy to also add the csv header line here. Sorry for this, but currently I am working a lot with csv files and it is astonishing how often the header line is omitted for no reason. Even for csv files with something like two dozen columns ...

Answer (score 0):

You make the second field with:

```
x = `expr $x + 1`
$count$x
```

The entire script becomes:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Type,Count,Name > test.csv
x=0
for f in `cat test.txt`
do
   x=`expr $x + 1`
   echo Def,u$x,$f >> test.csv
done
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Wo! Thanks! I missed that. Thanks for that! But I am stuck at how to write the "Data1, Data2 ... Data50" from the .txt to a new .csv file.

Comment: I tested this on my desktop pc using Cygnus, while doing stackoverflow on a notebook, so I had to type it over. Did I make a typing error?

Comment: you were right. I corrected using `cat`, with back quotes. Sorry for answering too fast :-)

Comment: I tried your code, but it seems the for loop is not working with the cat command

Comment: @TamaghnaGuhaThakurta don't forget about the back-quotes around `cat`. I tested this. And I am in another directory, so I omitted the `..` for the file names

Comment: Just to make sure I copied and pasted the entire code from the Cygnus (unix under windows) environment, where I tested this.

Comment: @TamaghnaGuhaThakurta Your welcome! Please don't forget to mark your chosen solution by clicking the V sign. This will help others with the same problem

Comment: @Roland, I have more than one column how to get single column using $f, In your answer $f returns complete line

Comment: @Pbms `read` can read multiple variables, just list the fields you want.  `while read -r first second rest; do ... done <file` which also removes the pesky problems with `for` behind the link in the previous comment.  If your fields are not whitespace-separated, you can use `IFS=,` to split on comma, for example.  All of this is very well covered in various FAQs.